# Responsive Design Mode on desktop does not behave the same on the actual device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a frustrating CSS problem. [I am building a a single page JS map application](https://bbq.crabdance.com/cca) and am trying to synchronize styles across browsers/devices. I thought I did a successful job using Responsive Design Mode in Safari/Firefox. It looks the same to me when I switch between iPad/Galaxy/iPhone/desktop in the browser emulator.

However, when I actually open the page on my phone in Firefox/Safari, it does not appear the same. Specifically, the ? button is wider than the rest of the buttons below it. I specifically have the width property explicitly set to 40 pixels in the CSS.

What is happening here? Why is the ? button wider?

Here are some screenshots of what I mean:

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcGSu.png)

[Desktop/Responsive Mode iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6hh4.png)

[Desktop/Responsive Mode iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVwxe.png)

[My actual iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMNCh.jpg)

I tried connecting my phone using Remote Debug but I don't really know how to use it without visualizing the actual phone screen so I can't see what I'm editing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: We can't help you fix problems with your code when you don't show the code to us! Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML and CSS in a [**minimal, reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what might be happening and be able to help.

Comment: It must be iphone specific. I test it on my pc and Mi Mix 2s works fine. I have a feeling that the button background is set to transparent on iphone. That results in black background as a preventative measure from inserting invisible buttons or something. My best guess is that not all of your styles load properly. Or perhaps your phone cashed previous version of css. I would recommend to avoid the use of !important. It should not be used only in extreme situations. It destroys the specificity system of css. Try to clear your cash. Replace !important with better selectors and keep me posted ;)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I included a link to the page where it is trivial to access the relevant documents.

Edit: I found the problem. For some reason, padding was being added in iPhone and not in responsive mode or other browsers. Adding padding:0 to the button fixed the problem.

Comment: The relevant code much be included in the question. Externals links can be acceptible, but *only* when provided along with the code. Also, the code must be a minimal reproducible example as per the link I gave you. We shouldn't be expected to go through your entire code base to help you solve the problem. You need to help us help you. Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason, padding was being added in iPhone and not in responsive mode or other browsers. Adding padding:0 to the button fixed the problem.